# How to load files from subfolder into the main package

Tags: python, import, package, setuptools

I have a python project with the following structure

```
package/__init__.py
package/foo.py
package/subFolder/__init__.py
package/subFolder/myModule.py
```

I would like to be able to import myModule on the level of package

```
import package.myModule
```

I've tried to import the modules inside the `package/__init__.py` with

```
from .subfolder import *
```

with no success...

Unfortunately I can't change the folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the autocomplete working, you could generate the `__init__.py` and fill `__all__` with appropriate symbols.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation correctly,
you have your project directory that contains your script and a sub-Folder that contains a file defining a module.

From your script in the project directory, to access your module, the following should work: 
`from subFolder.myModule import *`

Comment: Okey, but this only works when I list all modules inside the subFolder. What I would like is something like this:
`from subFolder.* import *`

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up with was to append all modules from the subFolder to the `__all__` Attribute in `subFolder.__init__.py` with the following snippet:

```
import pathlib
file_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.glob('*.py')
__all__ = [path.stem for path in file_path if '__' not in path.stem]
```

And in `package/__init__.py`:

```
from .generated_execution_layer import *
```

An ugly side effect of this is, that it broke autocompletion for this imported modules.